# Increasing height in span

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How to get the green `div` have the same variable height as the red `div`?
Meaning when the text in green grows, that then also the height of the red box grows to be the same as the green box.
I know I can remove the `span` from `.aaa`, but for other code impact this is not feasible solution. `.aaa span` has to remain.

```css
.aaa span {
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 1.6em;
}

.bbb {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  color: black;
  background: red;
}

.ccc {
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="aaa"><span class="bbb">Hello hello hello hello hello Hello hello hello hello hellotitle titletitle titletitle titletitle titletitle titletitle title</span>
    <span class="ccc">12345</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

f
f
f

Comment: Make your aaa flex, remove float from bbb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split up your first CSS rule like this:

```
.aaa {
  display: flex;
}

.aaa span {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 1.6em;
}
```

The `flex` property needs to be assigned to the container, not to the spans. And `float` isn't necessary.

```css
.aaa {
  display: flex;
}

.aaa span {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 1.6em;
}

.bbb {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: left;
  color: black;
  background: red;
}

.ccc {
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="aaa"><span class="bbb">Hello hello hello hello hello Hello hello hello hello hellotitle titletitle titletitle titletitle titletitle titletitle title</span>
    <span class="ccc">12345</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, that solved it! - will mark your answer when it allows me to do.